# How to get week number from custom date string

Tags: excel

I have this type of strings

```
DECW42012
JANW12013
JANW22013
JANW32013
JANW42013
JANW52013
FEBW12013
```

Can i somehow get week number (not in month but in year) from that string ?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=WEEKNUM(DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(LEFT(A1,3)&1),1),2)+(MID(A1,5,1)-1)`

Should do the trick.

Comment: I just realized that your formula return other week numbers than formula of Jeeper, interesting

Comment: Indeed. Please note that I have set the second parameter of WEEKNUM to 2 which means: "Number of the week in the year, with a week beginning on Monday". However I had a look at my system calendar which displays e.g. FEBW12013 as week number 5.

Comment: i just checked it in calendar too and it seems your formula is right, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the following,

`=WEEKNUM(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,3)&RIGHT(A1,4))+(MID(A1,5,1)-1)*7)`

[image: WEEKNUM function]

The [WEEKNUM function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/weeknum-function-HP010343016.aspx) has an optional *return_type* parameter that I have not implemented and that is one that you should pay close attention to if you wish to get the correct returns for your week numbe schedule.

*Edited:* dropped the week-of-month by 1 before multiplication

Comment: thank you, i set upper formula as solution because that return type was already implemented :)